# using jscript to create greyscale to colour effect on images

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am using the following technique to make my images go from greyscale to colour on hover: http://solemone.de/code/code-examples/demos-grayscale-hover-effect-with-html5-canvas-and-jquery/

The only issue I'm having is that when I hover the image it goes back to the original size instead of fitting in the the sytle width it has been set to.

jscript code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.imglist img').each(function() {
            $(this).wrap('<div style="display:inline-block;width:' + this.width + 'px;height:' + this.height + 'px;">').clone().addClass('gotcolors').css('position', 'absolute').insertBefore(this);
            this.src = grayscale(this.src);
        }).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#imglist1 a").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).find('.gotcolors').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
            }, 
            function() {
                $(this).find('.gotcolors').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
            }
        );


    });


    function grayscale(src) {
        var supportsCanvas = !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
        if (supportsCanvas) {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'), 
            context = canvas.getContext('2d'), 
            imageData, px, length, i = 0, gray, 
            img = new Image();

            img.src = src;
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            px = imageData.data;
            length = px.length;

            for (; i < length; i += 4) {
                gray = px[i] * .3 + px[i + 1] * .59 + px[i + 2] * .11;
                px[i] = px[i + 1] = px[i + 2] = gray;
            }

            context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
            return canvas.toDataURL();
        } else {
            return src;
        }
    }


    window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
        function(callback, element) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
    })();
</script>
```

cs code:

```
.imglist {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 0 0 -15px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
    .imglist li {
        margin: 0 0 0 15px;
        float: left;
    }
        .imglist { display:block }
        .imglist img { opacity:0; }
```

html code:

```
<li><a title="It's Me!"><img src="images/profile.jpeg" alt="Profile Picture" style="width:100%;"></a></li>
```

Any help or advice is welcome. Maybe there is a better and easier way of doing this? I originally tried doing it with css but didn't have much luck. Thanks.

Comment: I tried making a demo by copypasting your code and guessing what html you were missing, but it doesn't appear to do much: http://jsfiddle.net/s401gcpb/1/ -- a couple of questions: what is `requestAnimFrame` doing here (it doesn't appear to be used anywhere)? why the inline width on the `img`? why `opacity: 0;` in the css?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use CSS3? You can use a grey-scale filter with an animation on the hover like this ([source](http://labs.voronianski.com/css3-grayscale/)):

```
.animated-grayscale { 
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(grayscale.svg); /* Firefox 4+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
}
.animated-greyscale:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
}
```

This removes the greyscale on the hover, as you've requested in the original question. Here's the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/j0wm1oj5/

Comment: I took the liberty of editing it myself, hope you don't mind. It does appear however, that transition doesn't apply to the transition as it's coded there. This is the closest I could get to work in FF and Chrome (no luck in IE10) http://jsfiddle.net/7rbncpkg/1/

Comment: @xec Not at all. I think it's because of all the different browser prefixes for filter, you'd need to transition all of them. Best way around this is probably applying an 'all' transition and the filter to a specific class (as you have done in the fiddle) and applying this class (something like .animated-greyscale)